# Ionic React v5: Configure Project to Process Sass/Scss Files

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, sass

I've create a test application with Ionic v5 w/React and I don't see any specifics in the documentation on how to configure Sass preprocessing. I have a couple sass files in the project structure, but they don't seem to be loading or being processed for that matter. I added node-sass to the package.json. Any help would be much appreciated. I used the Ionic Cli to created a blank app and added some .scss files to the project dir.

Answer (score 11):

So I figured it out. Turns that ionic looks at the `themes` directory for all style sheets, including scss sheets. So I simply place my scss files there, ran `ionic serve` and imported the base style sheet, `import '/theme/styles.scss'` into the "main" component and it worked. I could run `ionic build` command see that the scss files were processed and minified into a .css file.

Comment: Thanks for adding the solution, this is useful to me.

Comment: This is great. I am puzzled it is not in the docs

Answer (score 9):

So just to make it clear that you do need to install `node-sass` via `npm` or `yarn` in order for Ionic to support scss files after that you can change any files whether it’s inside pages or components or theme folder and you just have to update the import to scss instead of css

Command for Installation
`npm install --save-dev node-sass`

Import changes
[image]